# Twitter Digits for web - How to set default country in embeddable widget

Tags: twitter, twitter-digits

I want to set my default country  to `+92` in Twitter Digits for web. This can be done on the button click event. But i don't want it on the button click.

```
function onLoginButtonClick(event){
  Digits.logIn({
    phoneNumber: '+92'
  })
    .done(onLogin) /*handle the response*/
    .fail(onLoginFailure);
}
```

I want to display embeddable widget with my default country. Any possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching from a few days. I figured it out form [twittercommunity](https://twittercommunity.com/) that  `phoneNumber: '+92'` , `accountFields` , `theme` can be passed to embed function

```
Digits.embed({
  container: '#my-digits-container',
  theme: {
   /* Input fields borders */
  },
  phoneNumber: '+92',
  accountFields: Digits.AccountFields.Email
})
.done(onLogin) /*handle the response*/
    .fail(onLoginFailure);
  };
```